# displaying the submitted values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to update the form values which I enter in the form to show as a list. I am trying to get the form values and display the values using local storage but I am not sure how to display the entered values inside a `div` tag with a class of `gettingValues`.

Can you tell me how to do it? I am providing my code below. I have put it in a Codepen too: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNjQRQ?editors=1010

```
<div class="gettingValues"> getting form values
    <input data-name="edit" type="button" value="Edit" name="editHistory">
    <input data-name="delete" type="button" name="deleteHistory" value="Delete">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the values submitted in the form in:

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
  });
```

Changing to:

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = "<div><span>"+$('#name').val()+"</span><span>"+$('#email').val()+"</span></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input.. 
    $('.gettingValues').append(div); //apendd the div
    $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form 
    localStorage.clear();
 });
```

But if you want then to click in 'edit' or 'delete' button and trigger some function, you must attach a bind funtion and set a 'id' or a unique identifier to know which user edit/delete.

If you want also to store the user submited, you could add a `$.get / $.post` function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: but when I submit in codepen...I just see this one You've just POSTed to a Pen.Values Posted ......but not sure how to see the values inside the div tag in the browser

Comment: you should put the `$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e){` function inside the document ready (not in the init()), and add jquery.js (if it isn't yet).

Comment: yeah I changed it in codepen but still not successful :( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMRmoZ?editors=1010

Comment: You miss the jquery and set the class to the div. Here a working codepen: http://codepen.io/jpaulet/pen/xVrWZq?editors=1010
Note that the alerts are fired.

Comment: yeah working but if I give second value it's not adding up...it's clearing the existing values  and disappears edit and delete buttons too :(

Comment: Yes, because for testing porposes I write 'html' instead of 'append'. Change that and it works fine, but I repeat, the edit/delete button will do nothing. You should read a jquery tutorial to accomplish that, like: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/jquery-dynamically-add-and-edit-table-rows-with-jquery-ui-dialog-1106.aspx or something similar.

Comment: Yes, you can. You could set a unique value for each added user (and instead of displaying span tags, use input) and dynamically generate the buttons "edit" and "delete" for each user and bind some function to each button, but SO is not for users do your code, for that I suggest to read or follow a tutorial to do this. There are a lot: 'jquery create edit delete users' or similar and also you could store in database etc.