# display all the values when i submit in form with edit and delete buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

- I am trying to display all the values when i submit in form with edit and delete buttons
- but right now they are displaying only one values...
- when i display new value the old value is replaced by new value...
- can you tell me how to fix it...
- providing my code in codpen below

http://codepen.io/schikara/pen/bpRMMq?editors=1010

```
$('#localStorageTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    var div = "<div><span>"+name+"</span><span >"+email+"</span><span>"+message+"</span><input type='button' value='Edit' name='editHistory'><input type='button' value='Delete' name='deleteHistory'></div>";  //add your data in span, p, input.. 
    //alert(div);

    $('.gettingValues').html(div); //apendd the div
    $('#localStorageTest')[0].reset(); //clear the form 
    localStorage.clear();
 });
```

Comment: Nice to see you again. I suggest you (again) to read a tutorial for doing this: http://www.infotuts.com/crud-example-php-jquery-ajax/  or grab a plugin like: http://js-grid.com/demos/ . With this you will have a functional (and mantainable code by you).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [displaying the submitted values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248151/displaying-the-submitted-values)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.gettingValues').html(div);
```

To

```
$('.gettingValues').append(div);
```

The html method sets the element's inner HTML, overwriting any html that may have already been there.  Append will just add the new div without overwriting the previous ones.

Comment: its working, but when I click delete button its deleting all the values  ...is it possible to delete only particular value http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grRKEz?editors=1010